# Update the quantity in the orderState duplicates?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

If I change an orders' quantity of an Object, then it duplicates the concerning Object in the State each time when I changes the quantity?

Assuming the action.payload.indexNumber is e.g. 2 and action.payload.quantity is 100.

This is the source code of orders.reducer.ts:

```
case OrderActions.CHANGE_QUANTITY: {
  const entities = [
    ...state.entities,
    {
      ...state.entities[action.payload.indexNumber],
      quantity: action.payload.quantity}
  ];

  return {
    ...state,
    entities
  };
}
```

How can I prevent the duplication of the concerning Object each time when I changes the quantity?

Please help me out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have found the resolution.. I have to use the slice() function to prevent the duplication. This is the new working code:

```
case OrderActions.CHANGE_QUANTITY: {
  const entities = [
    ...state.entities.slice(0, action.payload.indexNumber),
    {
      ...state.entities[action.payload.indexNumber],
      quantity: action.payload.quantity
    },
    ...state.entities.slice(action.payload.indexNumber + 1)
  ];


  return {
    ...state,
    entities
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

By using the spread operator (`...`), you create what's called a *shallow copy* — such a clone does not copy its members, but only stores them under a new reference. That's very different from *deep cloning*, which is known to be expensive.

In the case of Redux, it's not only fine to create new references for the updated objects — it's the way it must be done. Redux will compare the references to see what has actually changed, and take action based on that.